# How can I use map() to show my datas from API?

Tags: reactjs, api, dictionary

I am trying to display comments of an article from my API. So I used map to show my comments. When I console log my comments, I have a promise that shows all the datas from comments from my API.

When I use comments.map(), I have this error :[image: error with map]

I thought I have to go through "result" and "data". I console logged comments.result.data in order to use it through map but I had no data, it was empty...

This is the console log of comments :[image: my datas comments]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { API_URL } from '../config'
import { Skeleton } from '@material-ui/lab'
import { Grid, Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import { AiFillCaretLeft } from "react-icons/ai"
import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText'
import ListItemAvatar from '@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar'
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import CommentForm from '../Components/Forms/CommentForm'
import PostsAPI from '../Services/PostsAPI'
import CommentsAPI from '../Services/CommentsAPI'

export default function PostPage() {

    const {id} = useParams()
    const [post, setPost] = useState(null)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([])
    console.log(comments)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPost();
        fetchComments();
    }, [])

    const fetchPost = async () => {
        const data = await PostsAPI.findOne(id);
        setPost(data)
        setIsLoading(true)
    }

    const fetchComments = async () => {
        try{
            const comments = await CommentsAPI.findAll()
            setComments(comments.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <nav>
                <Link to="/">
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary"><AiFillCaretLeft /><span>Back</span></Button>
                </Link>
            </nav>
            <Grid container spacing = {2}>
                <Grid item sm={6}>
                    <div className='postImg'>
                        {isLoading ? <img src={API_URL + post.data.attributes.image.data[0].attributes.formats.small.url} alt={post.data.attributes.title} /> : <Skeleton variant="rect" width="100%" height={400} />}
                    </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={6}>
                    <h1>{isLoading ? post.data.attributes.title : <Skeleton variant="text" width={300} height={80} />}</h1>
                    <p>{isLoading ? post.data.attributes.content : 
                        <>
                            <Skeleton variant="text" height={25}/>
                            <Skeleton variant="text" width="60%" height={25}/>
                        </>
                    }</p>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item md={6}>
                    <CommentForm />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item md={6}>
                    {<List>
                        {comments.map((comment, i) => (
                            <ListItem key={i} alignItems="flex-start">
                                <ListItemAvatar>
                                <Avatar alt="Avatar" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
                                </ListItemAvatar>
                                <ListItemText
                                primary="Brunch this weekend?"
                                secondary={
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                    <Typography
                                        component="span"
                                        variant="body2"
                                        color="textPrimary"
                                    >
                                        {comment.pseudo}
                                    </Typography>
                                    {comment.content}
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                }
                                />
                            </ListItem>
                        ))}
                    </List>}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot an await. Do `const comments = await CommentsAPI.findAll()`.

Comment: Thank you Bas bas, I just added it. The problem is still the same.

Comment: What does `console.log(comments)` output now? If that is undefined, the problem may be in your API.

Comment: I have directly an object (instead of a promise) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZMe6.png

Comment: `comments.data.map(...)` should work. `Comments` doesn't seem to have property `results`?

Comment: I saw "result" in the promise but not in the array. You're right. :) Instead of using comments.data.map(...), I used setComments(comments.data). At least I don't have my app crashed but I don't see the values from my array displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`comments.results` evaluates to undefined because `results` prop does not exist

try comments.map(...) instead:

```
                    {comments.map(comment => (
                        <ListItem alignItems="flex-start">
                            <ListItemAvatar>
                            <Avatar alt="Avatar" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
                            </ListItemAvatar>
                            <ListItemText
                            primary="Brunch this weekend?"
                            secondary={
                                <React.Fragment>
                                <Typography
                                    component="span"
                                    variant="body2"
                                    color="textPrimary"
                                >
                                    {comment.attributes.pseudo}
                                </Typography>
                                {comment.attributes.content}
                                </React.Fragment>
                            }
                            />
                        </ListItem>
                    ))}
```

Comment: I tried but my app crashes... I have a blank page.

Comment: I updated my answer. I changed `comment.content` to `comment.attributes.content` to match your object structure

Comment: Great ! I used setComments(comments.data) instead of comments.data.map. I just updated my code.

Comment: Ok  I'll try it.

Answer (score -1):

I cant really see what ur objects contains, but you want to use those values i assume?

```
array.map((item, i) => {
return (
<p>{item.property}</p>
//...whatever more here...
);
}
```

Would be helpful if you can show us whatever propertys each object contains. :)

Comment: Thank you Freddy. Just changed the image, so you can have better look and understanding.

Comment: I saw you added a new argument "i". What does it represent ?

Comment: Ah perfect. :) The i is just the index, which you can use as a `key` value when mapping.

Also, as stated by someone else, make sure you are actually trying to map a array and not a object, otherwise it won't work. Let me know if that solves your issue or not. :) –

Comment: Thank you Freddy. At least, I don't have key warning any more...

Comment: I am trying to understand now how I can have the values from the array appearing. It looks like "comment.pseudo" and "comment.content" don't show anything.

Comment: Now it worked by using "comment.attributes.[pseudo/content]". Thank you for your help Freddy. :)

Comment: No worries. Glad u got it working